# How to Use navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:) in SwiftUI View Presented by UIKit's UIHostingController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

iOS developers!

I'm currently working on migrating my app to be compatible with iOS 16 and above. I've encountered an issue with the new navigation methods introduced in SwiftUI for iOS 16.

In the new API, programmatic navigation is supposed to be done using `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`. However, this method only seems to work when the view is inside a `NavigationStack`.

Here's the catch: the view I'm trying to navigate from is actually being presented from UIKit using a `UIHostingController` and then pushed onto a `UINavigationController`. Because of this, it doesn't seem to act like a `NavigationStack`, and as a result, the navigation doesn't work as expected.

Here's a simplified code snippet to illustrate my issue:

```
// UIKit Part
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIView())
navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)

// SwiftUI Part
struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Navigate") {
                isPresented = true
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented) { Text("New View") }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows a workaround to make `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)` work in this scenario?

Thank you for your time and expertise!

Comment: Facing the same problem. This is so frustrating. My workaround is using a hidden `NavigationLink` that is activated based on the state variable that is changed in a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have UINavigationContoller outside of SwiftUI, then you should do other navigation through UIKit. It means, instead of using `navigationDestination`, trigger some callback to do one more `navigationController?.pushViewController`

Consider using Combine's subject:

```swift
let router = PassthroughSubject<Route, Never>()
...
subscription = router.sink {
 navigationController?.pushViewController(newView, animated: true) 
}
...
Button("Navigate") { router.send(.newView) }
```